# PHP - Using a timer

Tags: php, mysql, date, time

Hello I want to make a timer of 1 minute and want to execute a mysql query after that.

Can I do this in PHP, without using any javascripts? If yes, how would I do it?

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this ? It seems quite strange for a script to wait such a big amount of time... online, 60 seconds is like an eternity now...

Comment: Wouldn't it make more sense to schedule a script to run every minute using crontab? Assuming you want to perform some db tasks, irrespective of client input (ie php on cli)

Comment: What is the reason you don't  want javascript?

Comment: Because I am not able to

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It'll be taxing in performance, and a very inefficient way of accomplishing the two-hour restriction on the password recovery check from your other question, which I'm assuming is why you asked. Add a timestamp column to the table (PHP `time()` function), and when you query the table for password recovery later, if the timestamp column (which will be a time in seconds) is 7200 (the number of seconds in two hours) less than the current timestamp, delete the row. If the difference is less than 7200 seconds, perform the recovery.

Answer (score 5):

You can call you script and add a `sleep(60)` in it. It causes the script to wait for 1 minute.

Comment: Watch out with max_execution_time ... by default, it's set on 30 seconds.

Comment: The max_execution_time only applies to the actual script execution.  System calls such as sleep() do not count against it.